# StatusBar MenuStripItem Select Mouse

Tags: c#, menustrip, statusstrip, toolstripmenu

I expose you my problem today. I created a statusStripLabel for showing the current name - the selected item of MenuStrip  or ToolStripMenuItem when the mouse is hover it. I have this code : ( it's working )

```
private void ouvrirToolStripMenuItem1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem houver = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    MenuStatusLabel.Text = houver.Text;
}
```

But I want make for all toolstripmenu  and no just one. ( a function or something like that )

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/254525/Automatically-display-Menu-on-Hover

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919907/set-statusbar-text-on-mouse-hover-works-for-controls-but-not-menuitems

Comment: I'm reading both of them but i don't understand !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fit from your problem and good solution, I modified the code from this [Link](http://www.hikaruyuuki.com/en/blog/display-tooltiphint-text-of-menu-items-in-status-bar-c-sharp.html)

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Ready...";
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip1.Items)
            {
                TraverseMenuItemHint(item);
            }
        }

        private void MenuHint_Hint(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = (sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Text;
        }

        private void TraverseMenuItemHint(ToolStripMenuItem element)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < element.DropDownItems.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!(element.DropDownItems[i] is ToolStripSeparator))
                {
                    ToolStripMenuItem item = element.DropDownItems[i] as ToolStripMenuItem;
                    if (item.Text.Length > 0)
                        item.MouseEnter += MenuHint_Hint;
                    TraverseMenuItemHint(item);
                }
            }
        }

        private void fileToolStripMenuItem_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Ready...";
    }
```